# Quaternion using only two angles?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm bound to use Quaternion on some openGL rotation. However the information I have are just two angles - representing the spherical vector rotation.

[image: dd]

It's the theta and psi from the image above. What I actually want to do is to rotate **object's back** towards the point `theta` and `psi` are pointing at.

You can see live javascript demo of what I'm trying to achieve here: http://fel.8u.cz/motion.html (requires device with accelerometer). I need to do this but through [`QQuaternion`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qquaternion.html).

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  Theta and psi don't indicate a point, they indicate a line.  By "object's back", do you mean the backside of some object?

Comment: Theta and psi indicate direction (technically, a line) and I'd like that line to be identic to z axis of the object.

Comment: A quaternion represents a relative rotation of a vector from a starting to an ending orientation. To use it to represent an absolute orientation, you need to be aware of what the starting orientation is, e.g. *û* (a.k.a. the *x*-axis). There are multiple conventions in that regard. Without that bit of information, the notion of a quaternion as a means of representing orientation makes little sense.

Comment: @KubaOber So I need to fetch some existing quaternion and rotate it by those angles? This can be done, just please tell me how to do it...

Comment: No. A quaternion represents **relative rotation** from (any) starting orientation. Euler angles (a.k.a. the first two spherical coordinate components) represent **absolute orientation**. It's literally apples and oranges. What gave you the idea that you can use quaternion as-is to represent orientation? You can't without deciding first where does the quaternion rotate *from*. You really need to understand what a quaternion is first, otherwise we'll be going in circles forever...

Comment: @KubaOber If you actually wanted to help, wouldn't you post an answer explaining the relationship between quaternion and absolute rotation?